# Tab Preview in Firefox ( Ctrl+Tab improved)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

On **windows 10 alt+tab**. **I want this behaviour in firefox for quickly getting an overview of the tabs.**
[image]

**Firefox** already has a hidden feature, which can be activated in `about:config` setting `browser.ctrlTab.previews` to true. Clicking ctrl+tab then gets. This is already nice, but that are only 5 tabs which is a bit useless to me. It would be nice, if this would not only use one row but 3 or 4 rows.

[image]

So does anybody know how to enhance this feature using more screen for previewing or knows an addon which implements this functionality?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but can you please do us a favor?  Utilize the native `imgur` image service within Super User, rather than `ibb.co`.  Many of us can't see screenshots hosted at that location.

Comment: @Run5k You mean like this? Why? Because this embedds better or because of trustworth?

Comment: Yes... thank you.  As you said, because they can be easily embedded and because some of us are blocked from accessing the `ibb.co` domain.